# Continuity of a complicated function with four parameters

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $k,l,p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ be four positive integers and let $f$ be the function defined by $$
f(x,y) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{x^k y^l}{x^{2p} + y^{2q}} & \mbox{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
        0 & \mbox{if } (x,y) = (0,0)
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
Show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ if and only if $$\frac{k}{p}+\frac{l}{q} > 2.$$

I have some trouble to find the good inequalities for the "if" part and the good sequences for the "only if" part.

Answer (score 2):

ΗΙΝΤ

Use polar coordinates: $$y=r\sin{t}$$ $$x=r\cos{t}$$ $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
where $t\in [0,2\pi)$

Comment: Shouldn't the interval be a half-closed interval?

Comment: @Botond yes..i edited.thank you for the observation

Comment: Oh I see, to put this in an easier way, I should make two cases : $p>q$ and $q \geq p.$